# React js crypt text with rsa to use it on a qr code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I would like to encrypt a text using rsa and then use the encrypted text on a qr, but I'm facing problems.

Can you give me a hand?

I'm using the following hybrid-crypto-js library, do you know where I'm wrong?

Error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `function` supplied to `QRCodeSVG`, expected `string`.
```

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qrcodereact-65xw4)

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import QRCode from "qrcode.react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Crypt, RSA } from "hybrid-crypto-js";

function App() {
  let rsa = async () => {
    console.log("rsa");
    var crypt = new Crypt({ md: "sha1" });
    var rsa = new RSA({ keySize: 1024 });
    let on = rsa
      .generateKeypairAsync()
      .then(keys => {
        var signature = crypt.signature(keys.privateKey, "Hello world");
        console.log("signature: ", signature);

        var encrypted = crypt.encrypt(keys.publicKey, "Hello world", signature);
        console.log("encrypted: ", encrypted);

        var decrypted = crypt.decrypt(keys.privateKey, encrypted);
        console.log("decrypted: ", decrypted);

        var verify = crypt.verify(
          keys.publicKey,
          decrypted.signature,
          "Hello world"
        );
        console.log("verify: ", verify);
        return verify;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    console.log("w", on);
    return "Hi";
    //return on;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <QRCode
        value={rsa}
        renderAs="svg"
        level={"H"}
        fgColor="#333"
        bgColor="#fff"
        key={`level-H`}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @messerbill: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `function` supplied to `QRCodeSVG`, expected `string`.

Comment: yep just like the error tells you: the `QRCodeSVG` component expects a string for the `value` prop. You passed in `rsa` which is indeed not a string but a function

Comment: `let rsa = async () => {` -> this is a function implementation :)

Comment: @messerbill: I'm not understanding, you could show me how to do it on codesandbox.

Comment: there are more that just one mistake...the architecture is not good at all. Are you familiar with promises?

Comment: @messerbill: Yes a bit.
But my doubt is if the module really works because calling only the function I get nothing.
It does not even print the console log.

Comment: step 1: generate your key (which is async). step 2: add that key to a `state variable` of your react component. step 3: pass this variable to `<QRCode` component. Now everytime when that variable changes react will rerender the component using the newly set value